# RewriteCond(htaccess ) for excluding a URL processed by Zend framework

Tags: mod-rewrite, zend-framework

The following is `mod_rewrite` config for `Zend` application(Refer to [Rewrite Configuration Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.rewrite.html)).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have installed `mod_status` and want to exclude `/server-status` URL from being processed by `Zend Controller Dispathcer`.
I have tried the following `RewriteCond`,but none of them work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(server-status) [NC]
```

And i got the following exception :

```
'ERROR CODE: 54dedae933247 - Page not found: exception \'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception\' with message \'Invalid controller specified (server-status)\' in /usr/share/php/project/libraries/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/project/libraries/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /var/www/myapp/application/My_Bootstrap.php(255): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /usr/share/php/project/libraries/library/Zend/Application.php(366): My_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /var/www/myapp/public/index.php(43): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}'
```

I think i can exclude this URL by extending `Zend_Controller_Action` and in `preDispatch`, exclude this URL,but i do not want do this ,because i must change the code and for other the same situation i must change code(dirty solution),and sometimes and i can not access the code.

What condition must i include to exclude `/server-status`?